# Extract animation vertices

Tags: three.js

I have an object loaded with GLTFLoader and an animation using `THREE.AnimationMixer`. I know I can get vertices of the object by using `.fromBufferGeometry().vertices` on the Mesh geometry. How can I get all the vertices during an animation and see how they change over the time? KeyframeTrack does not seem to modify geometry directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can get vertices of the object by using .fromBufferGeometry().vertices on the Mesh geometry.

It's not necessary to convert your geometry to `Geometry` (which is going to be removed from the library at some point). Instead you can access vertex information by working with the respective buffer attributes. The documentation page about [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) provides more details about this topic.

> How can I get all the vertices during an animation and see how they change over the time?

When using animation techniques like skeletal animation or morph target animation, it's important to realize that the actual vertex displacement happens in the vertex shader (GPU). If you need transformed vertices in your JavaScript code (CPU) for some reasons, you have to manually perform the respective vertex displacement. There is no library functionality that can do this for you right now. But you might find some code samples at the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) or at github.

Comment: I am not too familiar with buffer attributes yet so its easier to convert it to geometry. I got the question idea from https://www.iamnop.com/particles/. Do you have any idea of how could he make particles form these animations?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no time to study the app but it looks like that most of the animation is done on the GPU. There is actually an official GPU particles system example that might be useful to you. The code is more compact and uses the latest version of `three.js` so it should be a bit easier to get familiar with: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpu_particle_system.html