# AnimationClip (GLTF): How to get all points of a specific bone over time

Tags: three.js

I'm loading an animated model via a GLTF file. I would like to get all the points of a specific a bone over time and plot the points in 3d. I thought I would do this by looping through the VectorKeyframeTrack that's within the tracks array of AnimationClip. But when I look at the values in the Float32Array, they are all the same over time (the x, y and z don't change over time). As you can see in the screenshot, indices 0,1,2 are the same as 3,4,5 and so on... This is the same for every bone and is also the case on multiple models.

Does anyone know why this is or if there's a better way to do it?

By the way, the animated model animates fine and I've tried this with multiple models with the same result.

[image]

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago and received satysfying response. Hope it answers yours as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597737/7306664

Comment: Yes this is sufficient and explains why I can't seem to find the correct coords in the KeyFrameTrack. Thanks!